# Cannot connect or emit to Amazon ECS Socket.io Server via Socket.io from a HTML file located in S3 bucket

Tags: javascript, html, amazon-web-services, socket.io, amazon-ecs

I am having trouble connecting and emitting to an ECS Fargate Socket.io Server on AWS via Socket.io from a HTML file located in a S3 bucket in the same AWS region.

The ECS Fargate Server's code is as follows:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var AWS = require ('aws-sdk');

io.on('connect', function (socket){
  console.log('connection made');

socket.on('disconnect', function (socketds) {
  console.log("***********************************************");
  console.log("Disconnected");
});

socket.on('reconnect', function (socketds) {
  console.log("***********************************************");
  console.log("Reconnected");
});

socket.on('c_status', function () {    
  console.log("*********************************************");
  console.log("cstatus");
});

socket.on('app_message', function (mdata) {
    console.log("***********************************************");
    console.log("App-message:",mdata);
    socket.emit('command1',mdata);          
});

});

http.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

And the relevant code of the HTML file is as follows:

```
<script>
  const serverLocation = "http://application-load-balancer-dns-link:3000";
  const socket = io(serverLocation);
  function sendmsg() {
  var date = new Date();
  date.setHours(date.getHours() + 4);
  var datetm = date.toISOString().split('.')[0]+"Z";
  var node_id = $('#innode').val();
  var clid = "0";
  var msg = $('#message').val();       
  if (node_id.length === 1) {
    var unitcode = "0" + "0" + node_id;
  }
  else if (node_id.length === 2) {
    var unitcode = "0" + node_id;
  }
  else {
    var unitcode = node_id;
  }
  var mdata = datetm+unitcode+msg;   
  socket.emit('app_message',mdata);
  }
</script>
```

I have been at it for 2 days now and have not been able to figure it out. It just doesn't connect.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

If you need more information, please let me know.

Comment: Why the downvote? I would appreciate feedback from the voter about how can I make this question better?

Comment: its been long time, still have you managed to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

1) Try checking the inbound rules of the security group associated with that instance.
2) Outbound rules should also be configured as its bidirectional (By Default allows all)
3) If they are perfect. Check whether timeout occurs or any other exception.

Comment: Thanks for your reply; I checked the inbound and outbound rules of the associated security group; it's set to allow all traffic but I am still unable to connect.